# Populate combobox with JSON values

Tags: extjs

I need to populate combobox with JSON data. This is my store:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.GetShopSurvey', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.GetShopSurvey',

    model: 'Test.model.GetShopSurvey',

    storeId: 'GetShopSurvey',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost/webcontent/CShopSurveyWebApplet&SubFunc=GetShopSurvey',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    }

});
```

And my view:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.main.Announcement',
{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Test.view.main.AnnouncementController',
        'Test.view.main.AnnouncementModel',
        'Test.store.Personnel'
    ],

    store: {
        type: 'GetShopSurvey'
    },
```

And one of the items is:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Range',
    name: 'Range1',
    store: , //here I need store to load. For example json value is {"range": 70}
    displayField: 'range',
    autoSelect: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    disabled: true
},
```

I added fields to model with name and type of data. However, I don't know how to get data from JSON and parse it in combobox. I commented place where I need to put that value btw.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Range',
    name: 'Range1',
    store: 'GetShopSurvey',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'range',
    valueField: 'range',
    autoSelect: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    disabled: true
}
```

If this doesn't work can you give me more information like toolkit and extjs version please

Comment: I have. But i get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmptyStore' of undefined`

Comment: I thinks this is because the store isn't getting instantiated.
try with this in the view : 
`store:  Ext.create('Test.store.GetShopSurvey')`

Comment: If you need that store exactly once, add the store to the [`stores` array in the application](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-stores) (Application.js)

Answer (score 0):

You should create an store instance and then use it.Moreover, set its autoLoad config to **true** value.

Answer (score 0):

try loadRawData method

```
var jsonData = {'range':500};
combo.getStore().loadRawData(jsonData);
```